# Tetris block in C

Tags: c, tetris

I have a project for college to create tetris using dynamically allocated board that is representing the empty part with `.` . I wanted to create the blocks with each of their pieces individually for example the

```
O
O O O
```

block in Tetris would be described in an 2d dynamically allocated matrix like that:

```
tablo[0][((distX/2)-1)] = 'O';
/*tablo stands for board(the 2d allocated matrix) and '(distX/2)-1' was 
  used to start the block from top center of the board */
printf("\n");
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  tablo[1][((distX/2)-1)+i] = 'O';
}
```

**So my question is:**

- Is that efficient?
- Is there another way to make blocks and move them inside the board
  matrix that is easier?

With my solution of blocks I have a bit of a trouble finding the way to make them drop like a whole it's like drawing tetris.

Plus I was told to include a hard mode that tetris starts with some blocks or block parts on the board that is difficult with my solution.

Its my first time posting so please tell me if you need more information about my issue. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think that kind of code would be easier with a OO language.

Comment: I cannot use OO language I am instructed to use C :)!

Comment: It was only a thought, but maybe you could [look](https://code.google.com/p/simple-tetris-clone/) [at](http://www.c.happycodings.com/Games_and_Graphics/code32.html) [tetris](http://gtkboard.sourceforge.net/doc/doxygen/tetris_c-source.html) [clones](http://qntm.org/tetris) to see if you can use the same way to use the tetrominos.

Comment: you can write OO code in C. function pointers can be added to structs to form virtual method tables. all you need is an explicit `this` parameter.

Comment: I don't think i can manage that at my level!

Comment: You could also consider storing the blocks, instead of the grid. Each block would have 4 point of (x, y) coordinates (stored in a struct for example), and moving them would mean increasing/decreasing either x or y for every point. The grid would consist of the x and y limits, and those are checked when you want to move a block.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of Tetris game implemented in c

http://www.gladir.com/CODER/TURBOC/tetris.htm

in this first link the shapes are stored in separated bi-dimensional arrays
and added into a matrix that represents the board game. -Same principle as your idea -.
I think this kind of architecture might fit your needs because it is a bit like having your
pieces separated, which would be represented in an OO language with different objects from same parent classe Shape -for instance-.

Here is an other example of Tetris like in c, it seems more confusing than the
first link but it may help.

http://www.c.happycodings.com/Games_and_Graphics/code32.html